# geom_vline does not work on my boxplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I have created a faceted boxplot.  Now I need to add lines on the plot.  The line did not show up with my codes below.  Please kindly provide me some help! Thanks!

Data:

```
Year    |variable   |value
2001    |A          |39.605
2001    |A          |28.50759
2001    |A          |24.8132
2002    |A          |10.70765357
2002    |A          |7.8676
2002    |A          |16.05294712
2003    |A          |19.7847
2003    |A          |20.21635
2003    |A          |29.15491667
2001    |B          |50
2001    |B          |78
2001    |B          |90
2002    |B          |35
2002    |B          |62
2002    |B          |82.5
2003    |B          |49.5
2003    |B          |60
2003    |B          |84
```

Code:

```
pp <- ggplot(dta, aes(x=factor(Year),y=value)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  facet_grid(variable~.,scales="free_y") +
  theme_bw()
pp + geom_vline(xintercept = 2002) #The line didn't show.
pp + geom_vline(xintercept = as.numeric(2002)) #The line didn't show.
pp + geom_vline(xintercept = which(levels(dta$Year) =="2002")) #The line didn't show.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, try

```
pp + geom_vline(xintercept = which(levels(factor(dta$Year)) =="2002"))
```

You had specified `aes(x=factor(Year),...`, so you need to find the integer number of the factor level. `levels(dta$Year)` returns `NULL` because `Year` is not a factor in the original dataframe `dta`. so, you need to add `factor(dta$Year)` in your call to `geom_vline()`:

```
levels(factor(dta$Year))
#[1] "2001" "2002" "2003"
```

Note that this will work even if you change your input data as opposed to hard-coding a particular factor level like in [your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42525950/3817004).

Comment: Thanks so much - Uwe! Your answer helps me to understand levels() function and use it better in the future too!

Comment: @Angel I'm glad I could help. Perhaps, you may want to consider [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)?

Answer (score 0):

Got it! 
pp + geom_vline(xintercept = 2)